# Drag and drop layout designer

Tags: javascript, html, layout, drag-and-drop

Are there any tools (frameworks) to create web based layout desinger (something like in Visual Studio, but with html and javascript) - with drag and drop, ability to combine several html tags into one control, changing "control" properties on the fly (e. g. width, font, etc) and exporting layout into html (xml)? Looked at [jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There's http://jqueryui.com/ which has a bunch of stuff. I don't know of anything as plug and play as the rich interfaces like visual studio and such, but jQuery UI goes a long way, and it either supports plugins or will soon (can't remember). Forms are one thing people are still wanting with that...

Anyway, I'd say jQuery with jQuery UI is the closest I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ext Designer as a WYSIWYG tools for extjs

Answer (score 0):

Also check http://www.wakanda.org - OpenSource tool for designing web + mobile UI as well as DB backend in NoSQL.

Regards,

Gaurav

CTO at http://www.RetailEMall.com